# Make the content fit the width of the window

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I am a complete noob in making designs. However, I am trying to build a landing page with a mockup from [dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/10752229/attachments/2420059?mode=media). Everything was looking okay until I tried to make it responsive. The width of the elements doesn't fit the width of the screen when the screen width is less than 840 px or so

[This is the image of the page when the width is less than 840px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXNMV.png).

[This the image of the page when the screen is greater than 840px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v6mx.png)

I would be more than grateful if anyone could guide me here or point out what exactly is wrong.

HTML

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --primary-color: rgb(243, 145, 161);
  --secondary-color: rgb(60, 60, 146);
  --heading-font: 'Jomolhari', serif;
  --body-font: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  --body-text-color: rgb(151, 151, 151);
}

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  color: var(--body-text-color);
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 165.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 2.4rem;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--body-text-color);
}

p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

section {
  padding: 3.9rem 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
}


/* Header */

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  font-family: var(--heading-font);
}

.nav {
  height: 7.2rem;
  padding: 0 6rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.nav-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.list-items {
  margin: 0 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--body-text-color);
  transition: color .1s;
}

.nav-link::after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  transition: width .5s ease 0s;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  color: var(--secondary-color);
}


/* header ends */


/* hero section */

#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 6rem;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(247, 202, 210), transparent);
  background-size: cover;
}

.global-headline {
  color: var(--secondary-color);
  font-family: var(--heading-font);
  font-size: 5.5rem;
}

#hero p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 3rem auto;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: white;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 5rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
<!-- Header starts -->
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">
        <a href="" class="logo">Plant<i class="fas fa-fan fa-fw"></i>Bloom</a>
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li class="list-items">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-items">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-items">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Shop</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-items">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-items">
            <a href="" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag fa-fw"></i></a>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Header ends -->

<!-- hero section -->
<section id="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="global-headline">
      <h2>Fresh Flower,</h2>
      <h2>Perfect Gifts</h2>
    </div>

    <p>Send flower for someone you love</p>

    <a href="#" class="btn">SHOP NOW</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use a responsive css framework to manage all your layout tasks by using their documented classes on various elements. There are quite a few different ones, some with just basic layout rules, others with more features

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for the suggestion but I am just learning and trying to build something using just HTML and CSS.

Comment: Understand and all I am talking about is using css rules already created for you that also include various media query rules for different device sizes. If you are just learning it will be part of the learning curve that you won't need to focus on as much and can get to doing more involved tasks. Responsive css is only one of the complex branches of learning to do web development

Comment: hey.... https://jsfiddle.net/pg7re0dz/ since you delete the other question

Answer (score 1):

Use **Media Queries** for responsiveness of the site, Try Below Code!

```
/* Mobile first */
.container {
  
}

/* 840px and above */
@media all and (min-width: 840px) {
  .container {
  
  }
}
```

Learn more about CSS `@media`

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes you are right that community tackle many problems that coming from there but i cannot right a whole documentation for any coming query so to help people we have to route them to something more good thing But for your concern and negative review to answer, i am editing it.

Comment: FYI: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Thank's Man, can i use that link in my answer?